# R console command reminder

Tags: r

I have been using the R under windows and ubuntu. I noticed that when I type the command in the R console in Mac, at the bottom frame of the R console, it automatically display the command related parameters. For example when I type in "`read.csv`", the bottom would show "

```
read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
         dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...)
```

Does the Windows or Ubuntu R console has the similar configuration?

Comment: you could use `read.csv(<tab>`

Comment: TAB for autocomplete (even partial), double TAB for having the options printed out. This is in keeping with how the Ubuntu terminal works in general.

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct but related bits of functionality on the Mac.app console. The one you are describing is the display of the argument list as seen on the help page in the Usage section that appears as soon as you type a left-paren on the input line of the console. The other is tab-completion mentioned by @ilir. On the Mac and I suspect on Linuxen, the `utils::rcompgen` function is used for tab-completion and it has a fairly extensive help page. I have seen suggestions in rhelp postings that an Xwindows console session should be capable of the same arg-list display.

Comment: would you mind posting the link if you happen to have that, maybe for a lack of precision in describing my question, i did not find any related info on windows.

Comment: I wrote 'Xwindows', which is not the same as 'windows'. I see that Rstudio has gone "one better" and offers tab-completion AND arglist display in its implementation on the Mac. I would guess that they do something similar on other platforms